# How to reverse proxy to a react app using htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, apache, .htaccess, reverse-proxy

This is what I have:
wordpress site: http://35.240.238.94 
react app site: http://35.198.238.40

What I want to do:
Reverse proxy to the react app so that when I enter this url:
http://35.240.238.94/datastaging, the react app site (http://35.198.238.40) is served but the url shouldn't change.

To do the above, I have added this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^datastaging(.*) http://35.198.238.40/data [P]
RewriteEngine Off
```

I see the react app being served (tab title changes to the title of the app) but the page shown is blank and when I check the console it shows `Unexpected token <`. After further investigation the error points to the `<!DOCTYPE html>` line of my react app.

Any idea how to correct this and serve the react app properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is related to [Getting Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type text/html when serving ReactJS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589116/getting-cross-origin-read-blocking-corb-blocked-cross-origin-response-with-mim). This is the same answer given to that question.

===

Figured it out. Due to the reverse proxy, the browser was looking for the ReactJS app's static folder inside the Wordpress site's server instead of the React app server. I get the CORB warning since it was not getting the CSS file that it was expecting.

To fix I had to create another rewrite rule, this time for requests for the folder /static. My .htaccess file now looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^datastaging(.*) http://35.198.238.40/data/$1 [P]
RewriteEngine Off

# Rewrite rule for static folder
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^static(.*) http://35.198.238.40/static/$1 [P]
RewriteEngine Off
```

Hope this helps someone.