# Getting Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type text/html when serving ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, reverse-proxy, cross-origin-read-blocking

I have a Wordpress test site that reverse proxy to a reactjs app. However, a blank page is served and I see `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type text/html` on the console.

When I add a plain "Hello, World!" in public/index.html, the Hello World is shown but the rest of the page is not shown.

EDIT: 
To explain further, my wordpress site has a subfolder that serves reactjs app.

My reactjs app is: http://dspstaging.drwealth.com
My test wordpress site is: http://35.240.238.94
My url that serves the reactjs app is : http://35.240.238.94/datastaging

As you can see, http://dspstaging.drwealth.com works well, however, when I try to access via http://35.240.238.94/datastaging, only "Hello World" is shown, and console displays a CORB warning.

Comment: why was this voted down?

Comment: "why voted down?" possibly the links. Websites change with time; better to capture a minimal picture of your file directory structure, an exact error message, or similar to help the next person see if they're experiencing the same issue. I'm glad you asked this question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Due to the reverse proxy, the browser was looking for the ReactJS app's static folder inside the Wordpress site's server instead of the React app server. I get the CORB warning since it was not getting the CSS file that it was expecting.

To fix I had to create another rewrite rule, this time for requests for the folder /static. My .htaccess file now looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^datastaging(.*) http://35.198.238.40/data/$1 [P]
RewriteEngine Off

# Rewrite rule for static folder
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^static(.*) http://35.198.238.40/static/$1 [P]
RewriteEngine Off
```

Hope this helps someone.